# kendo grid groupable doesn't work asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, grouping

I have a kendo grid which is bound dynamically onclick button, the first click button I can make grouping of columns then after that in the second click or else I can't.

This is my kendo grid code:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: gridData,
                schema: {
                    model: model,
                    parse: parseFunction
                },
                pageSize: 20
            },
            scrollable : true,
            sortable: true,
            groupable: true,
            pageable: true,
            resizable: true,
            refresh: true,
            navigatable: true,
        });
```

Comment: Can you show your grouping code in your click event handler? Check out this example: http://jsbin.com/OTEmaQos/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: i have a submit button so i put the refresh of grid on the success event   $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.groupable(true); even that it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please see the linked example in above comments. Setting the

```
groupable
```

property alone will not group the data. You need to explicitly call the group method

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.group({ field: "foo" });
```

Comment: tghe problem is that i haven't a spcefic column to display , i choose which column i want to show dynamically

Comment: Add some logic to assign your groupBy column name to a variable and replace "foo" with your variable.

Comment: i don't want to make a scpecefic field groupable on after the first grid bind , all the fileds didn't support the groupable option after the first click button to bind data to kendo grid

Comment: Please show your submit handler and data binding code.